# What is the Q-point of the zener diode?

Tags: diodes, zener

[image: What is the Q-point of the zener diode?]

Is the Q-point f the zener diode in figure equal to its breakdown voltage of 4 V ?

Comment: voltage =voltage across zener diode when it is off
current=current the diode when zener diode is on

Answer (score 1):

"The operating point or Q point is defined by the intersection of the load line equation and the i-v curve of the diode"

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-071j-introduction-to-electronics-signals-and-measurement-spring-2006/lecture-notes/18_diodes2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The Q-point (that is the DC operating point) is defined by the quiescent current Iz,o through the diode and the corresponding voltage Vz,o (which slightly can differ from the "breakdown voltage Vz). The breakdown voltage Vz is the voltage that corresponds to a current Iz that is is 50% of the maximum alloed DC current Iz,max.

Comment: Just for completion. And in some books, it says "Zener diodes are specified at the point corresponding to 50% of the power rating.". I think the \$I_{z.max}\$ should dependent on \$P_{z,max}\$ and \$V_{z}\$. Right?

Comment: In this case since Rz=0 it doesn't matter at what current (above 0) you specify the zener voltage.

Comment: Yes. When \$R_{z}=0\$, \$V_{z}\$ has only one value, so \$I_{z.max}\$ can only have one value.

Comment: Is there any real device with rz=0? (I urgently recommend to use small symbols and not capital letters for differential resistances). For each non-linear device a static as well as a dynamic resistance can be defined - and it is absolutely necessary to distinct between the two values.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biasing:

> The operating point of a device, also known as bias point, quiescent
>   point, or Q-point, is the steady-state voltage or current at a
>   specified terminal of an active device (a transistor or vacuum tube)
>   with no input signal applied.

Assume the zener is off
$$
V_{zener} = V_{R3.6V} = \frac{3.6k\Omega}{11k\Omega+3.6k\Omega} \approx 4.9V
$$
So, zener diode should be on, becuase \$R_{z}=0\$ (that means when the voltage on it greater than the breakdown voltage, it can flow through any current). The Q-piont is just equal to the zener voltage, that is 4V.

Comment: Not necessarily true, for certain values of the two resistors. I'll not say if it's true for the specific values given...

Comment: Yes, this is a very "ideal case". And can you give some more explanation?

Comment: Yes, i miss something.

Comment: Edited version is good.